# swapping nodes in single linked lists

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

I searched around on stackoverflow and couldn't find a clear answer to this question. How can I swap node positions in a single linked lists?

So far I have this...

```
temp = curr.next;
curr.next = prev;
prev.next =temp;
```

where curr is the current node and prev is lagging one node behind.

It makes sense when I draw it out but I'm historically shaky on linked lists and keeping track of references so if anybody could confirm it for me or explain to me what's wrong I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Why don't you try and let us know if this works?

Comment: Well how does it behave when you try to use it? Are you just *assuming* that something's wrong? Do you have unit tests?

Comment: Depends on how you wrote the method. What do you return and to where?